# Can I clone a disk with windows 10 and ubuntu to a bigger ssd?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, cloning

I was thinking of cloning my 500gb nvme ssd which has dualboot windows 10 and ubuntu to a new 1tb nvme ssd. I was thinking of using a gparted live usb to "copy" all the partitions to the new ssd via usb and be able to resize partitions using the graphical user interface for both windows 10 and ubuntu to take advantage of the bigger space. I'm wondering if anyone has tried this before and was successful

Answer (score 2):

Provided you installed the partition into lvm + filesystem yes.

You can just use

```
dd if=/dev/disk_old of=/dev/disk_new status=progress
```

Verify the new drive has the same information on it's partition table:

```
fdisk -l /dev/disk_old /dev/disk_new
```

If they say the same thing, you're golden.

At this point is the time shutdown and remove the old disk drive. If you don't want to remove the old disk drive, or you just want to be cautious you're going to have to run:

```
sgdisk -G /dev/disk_old
*OPTIONALLY, to delete it*
sgdisk --zap-all /dev/disk_old
```

You cannot have two disks with the same UUIDs on the machine without causing trouble and this makes sure that the old drive has a new one. Remember this dd command is a byte for byte clone, so it has the same UUID of the original drive.

Comment: GParted has an option to create a new UUID for a partition. Confirm the new UUID is also applied in fstab and grub.cfg.

Comment: I was scared of copying partitions using gparted on a live usb might mess with my Windows 10 install so I used Macrium Reflect within Windows to clone the disk. The cloning was successful but now I can only go into Ubuntu and not into Windows. Exactly the opposite outcome I wanted. When grub bootloader shows up and I try to go into Windows I get this error message:
 
error: Secure Boot forbids loading module from (hd8,msdos5)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/parttool.mod
error: can't find command -drivemap'-
error: bad shim signature.
 
Press any key to continue...

Comment: @xandrewx86 This clone program didn't make a byte for byte copy. Few things do, and that is why I recommended to use the `dd` command, because that's exactly what it does. You get an EXACT image of the source, UUID's partitions, and everything exactly as it was. These programs re-write or try to figure out everything and then re-code it on the drive. It's not the same thing.